# Stackoverflow exception during during DGV cell value change Event triggers

Tags: c#

i am trying to multiply the value of two cells from DGV and saving it to another cell.
but aim getting stackOverFlow Exception.

```
        private void ReturnCartDGV_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            long totalPrice;
            int rowIndex = ReturnCartDGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            totalPrice = (Convert.ToInt64(ReturnCartDGV.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].Value) * Convert.ToInt64(ReturnCartDGV.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].Value));
            this.ReturnCartDGV.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].Value = totalPrice.ToString();
            
        }
```

Comment: You're not considering the Cell that's triggering the event (this information comes from DataGridViewCellEventArgs). So you change the value of a Cell in the event that notifies the change, causing an endless loop -- What is the DataSource of this Control? If it's a DataTable, add an Expression to the Column that produces the calculated value (and make that Column in the DGV read-only). If you have a class model, do the same with a Property, with a private setter

Comment: Is your problem solved by the below answer?

Comment: I add an if condition for the column index checking but still getting StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the `Value` of a cell in the `CellValueChanged` event handler, which will raise the `CellValueChanged` event, which will continue on ad infinitum until the stack overflows. You are only interested in the `Value` changing in two specific columns, so you should be checking whether the event was raised by a cell in either of those two columns. If it wasn't then you don't do anything. The `e` parameter will tell you which column the cell was in whose `Value` changed.